# Material does not react to light and looks shadeless

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I have a problem importing old Blender files that I created with Blender internal. I am now using Blender 2.8 and a Principled BSDF.  When I render the object or set Viewport shading to Rendered, I don't see any shading. The objects don't react to the light. They look like materials in Blender Internal when the "shadless" option is checked. [image] When I set the Viewport shading to Look Dev, the material looks much better, but even here it doesn't really react to the light properly. [image] Newly created files are shaded correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

1. The main problem was that the unit system was set to "none". I set it to "metric" (Context Scene), and then scaled down my object to 0.1. Then the light worked as expected.
2. I also had to reduce the strength of the background to 0.2 (Context World).

Is there a good summary of what needs to be considered when switching from 2.79 to 2.8?

Comment: Mostly a UI overhaul really. That being said, in my opinion, switch asap—instant workflow improvement and much better defaults.

Comment: Oh, the only big difference (for me) was Collections—a vast improvement on the 2.79 layer dock. Collections is just a standardized, modern layer system.